# other functions the look similar to the hyperbolic sine function

Tags: functions, exponential-function, special-functions, hyperbolic-functions

This is probably an easy question, but I am looking for other simple functions that behave similar to the hyperbolic sine function. I have a chart below. Basically I am looking for other functions whose derivatives increase in either the positive or negative directions as the value of $x$ gets farther from the origin. Further, the domain should be from positive infinity to negative infinity and the codomain should also be from negative infinity to positive infinity. I am not sure if this class of functions has any special names.

[image]

Note that I am not looking for cubic equations which can have 3 zeros. I am looking for something that passes through the origin and behaves in this manner.

Any suggestions? I am doing some modelling of a particular phenomena and some of the pieces behave in this way.

Comment: You could always vary the coefficients or exponents. Then the result could be stretched or shrunk, or made not symmetric.

Comment: Haha, yeah, sorry @AlfredYerger I am probably like way overcomplicating my thought process. I am a statistician and not so much an applied mathematician, so trying to think about a function that behaves like this but has nice properties for an applied math model.

Answer (score 1):

Take any function $f(x) > 0$, any $a \ge 0$, and let your function be $$F(x) = a x + \int_0^x (x-t) f(t)\; dt$$ Note that $F(0) = 0$, $F'(0)=a$, and $F''(x) = f(x)$.

Comment: Nice. Yeah, this is kinda what I was working on, but in a discrete case. But this is helpful. Thanks for your help here.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a cubic of the form
$$
y = ax^3 + bx  
$$
with positive $a$ and $b$.

The only root is at the origin and the derivative behaves as you wish. You can vary the coefficients to get a shape that makes sense in your model.

Comment: Haha, of course this makes sense. Man, I was totally overthinking it. Thanks.